# Image Black Point Compensation in Java

Tags: java, image, colors

I have been using ColorConvertOp to convert grayscale images in Java but have noticed that sometimes they end up loosing a lot of the mid tone colors and look darker than they should.  I looked into it and discovered that Photoshop uses Black Point Compensation (BPC) to compensate for this issue.  I found an article for BPC [here](http://www.color.org/AdobeBPC.pdf) but it's a little technical for me.  Does Java support this natively using rendering intents or something, or am I going to have to figure out how to implement the algorithm explained in the document?  I understand BPC happens because the absolute blacks are different colors within the color spaces but I need to use BPC to get the images looking the same.  Any ideas?

I currently use the following code to convert to a new color space.

```
private void convertToColorSpace(ColorSpace colorSpace) {
    RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    hints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(colorSpace, hints);
    image = op.filter(image, null);
}
```

**NOTE:** ImageMagick is not an option, so please don't include it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution mostly working based off of a black point compensation ISO draft, meaning it isn't standard yet, found [here](http://www.color.org/BlackPointCompensation.pdf).  The process, including variable names, and complete steps are very well defined.  I couldn't find anything native to Java, though there is a [Little CMS](http://www.littlecms.com/) library written in c, which can probably be used with JNI.